# Erro ao executar .jar no Windows PowerShell com Maven

Tags: java, maven, cmd, powershell

Estou tentando executar esta ferramenta (CPA - https://github.com/CityPulse/cpa). Através do link disponibilizado, realizo o download das classes.
Após isso, executo o Maven, que gera um .jar. O arquivo de configuração (pom.xml) utilizado no Maven é este: https://github.com/CityPulse/cpa/blob/master/pom.xml

Após instalar o Maven, ele gera a pasta "target" com o .jar citado acima. Ao tentar executar este .jar, inicia-se o problema.

**Em todas minhas tentativas, tenho recebido o seguinte erro:**

```
"Erro: Não foi possível localizar nem carregar a classe principal com.ericsson.research.iot.citypulse.CityPulseInterface"
```

**Este é o comando que tenho executado:**

```
.\java -jar C:\Users\Vinicius\Documents\GitHub\cpa\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin\target\cpa-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

**O arquivo MANIFEST.MF está assim:**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven
Built-By: Vinicius
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_73
Main-Class: com.ericsson.research.iot.citypulse.CityPulseInterface
```

**Meu diretório das classes e o local onde está o .jar:**

```
JAR: C:\Users\Vinicius\Documents\GitHub\cpa\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin\target

Classe: C:\Users\Vinicius\Documents\GitHub\cpa\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin\target\src\main\java\com\ericsson\research\iot\citypulse
```

Fiz várias alterações no nível de diretório, colocando o .jar inclusive no mesmo das classes (dentro do package), porém o erro prosseguiu.

Obs: JAVA_HOME e PATH já estão configuradas. Utilizo Windows 10.

Answer (score -1):

Bom dia amigo! Pelo que entendi, o erro ocorre porque o comando para executar o **JAR** não está encontrando a classe principal do programa. Isso pode estar ocorrendo por diversos motivos, como a localização incorreta do JAR ou a configuração inadequada do arquivo **MANIFEST.MF**.

Uma possibilidade é que a estrutura de diretórios no JAR esteja incorreta. Certifique-se de que a classe principal esteja localizada em um diretório com o mesmo nome do pacote da classe. Por exemplo, se a classe principal está em `com.ericsson.research.iot.citypulse.CityPulseInterface`, ela deve estar em um diretório chamado `com/ericsson/research/iot/citypulse/` dentro do JAR.

Além disso, verifique se o nome da classe principal está escrito corretamente no arquivo MANIFEST.MF. O nome da classe deve ser especificado com o nome do pacote completo, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
Main-Class: com.ericsson.research.iot.citypulse.CityPulseInterface
```

Por fim, certifique-se de que o JAR esteja sendo executado com o comando correto. O comando que você está utilizando parece estar incorreto. Tente executar o JAR com o seguinte comando:

```
java -jar C:\Users\Vinicius\Documents\GitHub\cpa\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin\target\cpa-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

Certifique-se de que o comando java esteja no PATH do sistema e que você esteja executando o comando na pasta correta. Se o problema persistir, verifique se há algum erro no console do Maven durante a compilação do projeto. Isso pode indicar problemas com as dependências ou configurações do projeto.

E ao criar o arquivo **.jar** com o **Maven**, ele deve encapsular todas as classes e dependências necessárias para a execução da aplicação. Pelo que entendi, você está tentando executar o arquivo **.jar** a partir do diretório onde ele foi gerado (**target**), mas o erro que está ocorrendo indica que a classe principal não está sendo encontrada. Isso pode indicar que as classes não foram incluídas corretamente no arquivo **.jar**.

Uma possível solução seria verificar as configurações do arquivo **pom.xml** utilizado pelo Maven para gerar o **.jar** e garantir que todas as dependências e classes necessárias estejam sendo incluídas corretamente. Também é importante verificar se o Maven está instalado corretamente e configurado no PATH do sistema.

Outra opção seria tentar executar a aplicação diretamente a partir das classes compiladas, sem gerar o arquivo **.jar**. Nesse caso, seria necessário garantir que todas as dependências estejam no classpath da aplicação.

Espero ter ajudado!